# Trying to catch headers with python / selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, urllib2

I have this selenium test that opens a site locates an element on it and clicks it which takes it to the next page.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
element = driver.find_element_by_link_text("XYZElement")
element.click()   // click URL (old-url)
```

Which works as expected....

The thing is that on click() the website triggers a script which replaces the original link (old-url) and redirects you to a new page (new-replaced-url) ....

How can I catch that script and all the headers and variables that are passed along?

Sort of like this

```
import urllib
feeddata = urllib.urlopen('http://www.mysite.com/content/new-replaced-url').read()
```

With this second method I can get all the headers of the new URL (new-replaced-url) but miss the ones that happened just before after my old URL got replaced ....

really hope this makes any sense ..... :D
Thanks,
Uros

Comment: You could use Chrome to see how is conformed the request with headers, variables, etc. But Selenium is just for web-testing, I think it isn't for what do you want.

Comment: you may want to use a proxy.

Comment: I know Selenium is for webtesting ..... and that is what I am doing ... Basically I need to test the 302 redirect if it grabs the correct URL 

What do you mean by using a proxy?